# Mask or replace column values mysql any column data

Tags: mysql

How can we select any column values and mask them with a default value;

Example table called pet:

```
+--------+-------+-----------+
|  name  | owner | species   |
+--------+-------+-----------+
| Elvis  | Tom   | Dog       |
| Harley | Mary  | Cat       |
+--------+-------+-----------+
```

We want to mask name column with 'MASKED'. I used this select query but is there a better way?

```
select 
   case name
     when 'Elvis' then 'MASKED'
     else 'MASKED'
   end as name
 from mysql.pet;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------+
  name              |
+-------------------------------+
| MASKED                        |
| MASKED                        |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: isn't this enough? `select 'MASKED' as name, owner, species from pet` otherwise you have to better explain what you want to accomplish

Comment: You do not need the case expression, just use `'masked' as name`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to mask all values on column `name` with "Masked":

```
SELECT 'MASKED' AS name, owner, species 
FROM pet
```

If you only want to mask a specific name (e.g. "Elvis") you can use the following (using `CASE`):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'Elvis' THEN 'MASKED' ELSE name END AS name, owner, species 
FROM pet
```

You can also replace the value with a specific char (like `*`):

```
SELECT LPAD('', LENGTH(name), '*') AS name, owner, species
FROM pet
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=570bae4191561b558706a606a0e8f777)

Comment: Thanks. It is really simple and helpful to use SELECT 'MASKED' AS name, owner, species FROM pet

Comment: To skip last character: SELECT CONCAT(LPAD('', LENGTH(name), '*'), right( name, 2)) AS name, owner, species
FROM pet